# Vertical centering in table

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

How can I center something vertically?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in}  >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{1.2in} }
    \begin{overpic}
        [width=0.16\textwidth]{conn}
        \put(75,70){1}
        \put(16,70){2}
        \put(16,21){3}
        \put(75,21){4}
    \end{overpic} 
    & 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
        1 & Sensor+ \\ \hline
        2 & Sensor- \\ \hline
        3 & TEC- \\ \hline
        4 & TEC+ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Connector}
\label{fig:conn} 
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome! Please complete your question, and post a full compilable code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pictures are a special case in LaTeX when it comes to vertical alignment. Text baseline is usually the lowest line in a picture and the whole picture is above the baseline, that's why the `m` specification does nothing. In this case, a simple center alignment command `$\vcenter{\hbox{...}}$` can easily do the job. It only works in math-mode, though, so you need `$ .. $` outside.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[abs]{overpic}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2in}  >{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.2in} }
    $\vcenter{\hbox{%
    \begin{overpic}[width=0.16\textwidth]{example-image-A}
        \put(75,70){1}
        \put(16,70){2}
        \put(16,21){3}
        \put(75,21){4}
    \end{overpic}}}$ 
    & 
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|} \hline
        1 & Sensor+ \\ \hline
        2 & Sensor- \\ \hline
        3 & TEC- \\ \hline
        4 & TEC+ \\ \hline
    \end{tabular} 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Connector}
\label{fig:conn}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```